# How to make a dictionary from a list that contains values that are repeated

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I am new to python and I have struggling for a while in trying to convert the following list into a dictionary.

```
lst = ['AB_MK1230', 'MK12303', 86.17, 'AB_MK1230', 'MK12302', 89.99, 
'AB_MK1230', 'MK12301', 93.82, 'AB_MK1230', 'MK12301', 94.81, 'AB_MK1230', 
'MK12303', 87.5, 'AB_MK1230', 'MK12302', 94.67, 'AB_MK1230', 'MK12302', 90.32, 
'AB_MK1230',  'MK12303', 89.26, 'AB_MK1230',  'MK12301', 91.75,'AB_MK1230', 
'MK12302', 88.54, 'AB_MK1230', 'MK12303', 92.5,'AB_MK1230', 'MK12301', 93.49, 
'AB_MK1230', 'MK12301', 86.47,'AB_MK1230', 'MK12302', 84.79,'AB_MK1230', 
'MK12303', 86.57,'AB_MK1230', 'MK12301', 79.24,'AB_MK1230', 'MK12302', 80.34, 
'AB_MK1230', 'MK12303', 76.88]
```

AB_MK1230 is the parent sector and MK12303, MK12301 and MK12302 are the child sectors. My output is to have a dictionary with the key of each child sector and the parent sector and float values as the values for that key, something like the following.

```
dict = {MK12301: AB_MK1230, 93.82, 94.81, 91.75, 93.49, 86.47, 79.24
        MK12302: AB_MK1230, 89.99, 94.67, 90.32, 88.54, 84.79, 80.34
        MK12303: AB_MK1230, 86.17, 87.50, 89.26, 92.50, 86.57, 76.88 }
```

I have read some documentation from https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html?highlight=dictionaries but I still can't figure out the solution.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: [What have you tried? What's the specific problem? (c)(r)(tm)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274630/should-we-add-a-do-my-work-for-me-close-reason)

Comment: 0)your target `dict` is not a valid Python data structure 1) each iteration, read 3 items from a list and process them as necessary

Comment: But does this same principle that you mentioned apply for 100K records where the records for parent and child vary? I did not put the code I tried because it did not simply get me to any clue to my final solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We iterate over the list, unpacking three items at a time in `(parent, child, value)`-order. Using `(parent, child)` as a key into a dictionary we then add the value into a `set`.

```
import itertools
import collections

lst = ['AB_MK1230', 'MK12303', 86.17, 'AB_MK1230', 'MK12302', 89.99, 
'AB_MK1230', 'MK12301', 93.82, 'AB_MK1230', 'MK12301', 94.81, 'AB_MK1230', 
'MK12303', 87.5, 'AB_MK1230', 'MK12302', 94.67, 'AB_MK1230', 'MK12302', 90.32, 
'AB_MK1230',  'MK12303', 89.26, 'AB_MK1230',  'MK12301', 91.75,'AB_MK1230', 
'MK12302', 88.54, 'AB_MK1230', 'MK12303', 92.5,'AB_MK1230', 'MK12301', 93.49, 
'AB_MK1230', 'MK12301', 86.47,'AB_MK1230', 'MK12302', 84.79,'AB_MK1230', 
'MK12303', 86.57,'AB_MK1230', 'MK12301', 79.24,'AB_MK1230', 'MK12302', 80.34, 
'AB_MK1230', 'MK12303', 76.88]

d = collections.defaultdict(set)
for parent, child, value in itertools.zip_longest(*[iter(lst)]*3, fillvalue=None):
    d[(parent, child)].add(value)
```

d is now a dictionary like

```
defaultdict(set,
            {('AB_MK1230', 'MK12301'): {79.24,
              86.47,
              91.75,
              93.49,
              93.82,
              94.81},
             ('AB_MK1230', 'MK12302'): {80.34,
              84.79,
              88.54,
              89.99,
              90.32,
              94.67},
             ('AB_MK1230', 'MK12303'): {76.88,
              86.17,
              86.57,
              87.5,
              89.26,
              92.5}})
```

It's not entirely clear how your final data structure is supposed to look like. If you only want `parent` as the top-level key, you can use a nested `defaultdict`...

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! This worked like a charm and this the solution that I was trying to achieve.

Comment: One question I have on this data structure: Can it get the values in the order they appear? That is, {('AB_MK1230', 'MK12301'): 93.82, 94.81, 91.75, 93.49, 86.47, 79.24}, (...,...): {...}}

Comment: Instead of `d = collections.defaultdict(set)` use `d = collections.defaultdict(list)` and instead of `d[(parent, child)].add(value)` use `d[(parent, child)].append(value)`